# C++, Print to screen even with > file.out in command line

Tags: c++

I am manipulating characters from a file and sending them to another file using command line (which I am pretty new to).

```
a.out -d 5 < garbage01.txt > garbage02.txt
```

The characters are going to garbage02.txt through cout.put(char). If the command line arguments don't validate I just want to print to screen a simple message to state that, but everything goes to garbage02.txt. Changing the layout of the command is not an option.

I hope this is a pretty straight-forward issue, that I am just having difficulty finding a solution to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common to write error messages to `stderr` and normal output to `stdout`. To print an error message to `stderr` do

```
std::cerr << "Something went wrong\n";
```

(You can also do this with `fprintf`, but that is usually not needed.)

Output written to `stderr` will not be redirected by

```
> someFile
```

but only by

```
2> someFile
```

so the user can choose where they want to see the "normal" and the "error" output separately.

`std::cerr` also has the nice property that it does not buffer the output (unlike `std::cout`). That means that the user will see the error message before the program continues after the output line.

If you do not want this non-buffer functionality, use `std::clog`.

Comment: [`std::log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) is `cmath::log`. You need to use [`std::clog`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/clog)

Comment: std::cerr << "Something went wrong\n" , was just the simple, clean piece of code I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use /dev/tty file for that, it is a special file representing terminal for current process.

```
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream screen("/dev/tty");
screen<<"Your message"<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `std::cerr` to print to screen

```
std::cerr << "Some message" << std::endl;
```

or change your terminal command

```
a.out -d 5 < garbage01.txt 2> garbage02.txt    # Redirect stderr stream only
```